# Understanding custom elements inserted by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've stumbled upon something I cannot wrap my head around.

If I wrap an element with something like

```
var htmlWrapper = $("<custom-wrapper></custom-wrapper>");
$(".some-selector").wrapAll(htmlWrapper);
```

the DOM will have the element "custom-wrapper" and work as a block element to my understanding

Is this a part of web components? In such a case it should not work with Edge, but it works fine.

Comment: I can't find a canonical reference, but I believe that any elements which are not part of the specified doctype for the page are treated as a generic block level element. In any case, you should never use non-standard elements. If you want to create you own elements, then you can define your own [custom elements](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) or even your own doctype. It's a lot of work for almost no benefit, though. In fact I'd say it probably creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: It is not HTML standard tag (i.e. it is not par of the HTML Namespace) but modern browsers treat unknown tags pretty much like `div`.

Comment: okay, this makes sense. Is it still considered bad practise?

Comment: To create non-standard elements? Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Also in a dynamically added context, say another wrapper like a <b> for text? Since web components are still not fully supported by edge